# Write JPA entity with foreign key id, read joined entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, `A` and `B` that are persisted to a relational database via JPA.

```java
public class A {

   @Id
   private String id;
   private String bId;

}

public class B {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String field;
}
```

Notice how `A` does not have a `B` attribute but rather just its id. In my use case at the time of persisting an `A` entity the `B` entity does not currently exist and is written later to the db. However, at read time I would very much like to access `A` objects with their corresponding `B` entity if it already exists in the database (or null otherwise) - with a single JPA query.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken a look at JPA relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a joined HQL/JPQL query along with an projection in order to achieve what you need. For example consider the following repository, entities and projection classes:

1. Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

   @Query("SELECT P.id AS id, P.detailsId AS detailsId, P.name AS name, PD as detail "
   + "FROM Person P "
   + "JOIN PersonDetails PD "
   + "ON P.detailsId = PD.id")
   List<PersonDetailProjection> findJoined();

}
```

2. Entities

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long detailsId;

}
```

And

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "PersonDetails")
@Table(name = "person_details")
public class PersonDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String address;

}
```

3. Projection

```
public interface PersonDetailProjection {

    Long getId();
    Long getDetailsId();
    String getName();
    PersonDetails getDetail();

}
```

You can modify the query to have a `WHERE` clause, but the basic gist is what you see. Note that I still fail to see why you would want to do the query like, especially considering the amount of work it takes to set it up.

Comment: Hi @akortex thanks for your answer, I don't believe it would help me in my situation. In my use case entity `B` is not related to `A` (in your case `PersonDetails`), the relationship many to one in my case. So multiple `A` could refer to a single `B`, and `B` is unaware of which `A`s have a pointer to it. Hence the class definitions I put in place. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I can provide you with an another answer, but why are you over-complicating things like so? I mean your database design is quite weird.

Comment: I agree it is quite weird, however that's the way it is. If you want a more concrete example, try to think of `Person` and `Song`. `Person`s have a favourite `Song`, multiple `Person`s could have the same favourite `Song`, and `Song`s are otherwise unrelated to `Person`s so I wouldn't want a `Song -> List<Person>` link to exist in the `Song` entity. When persisting a `Person` their favourite Song obviously exists but all the `Song` data might not be persisted yet (waiting for an event to populate the table). Does that sound more realistic?

Comment: Added something that could be helpful.

Comment: I understand it looks weird. Your answer's really good! Thanks!! Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it with JPA's supported keywords for method names? (I mean `findByXWhereY` type of thing). I suppose not as the `Projection` object is just an interface with no JPA annotations but I thought it'd be worth exploring the option. Thanks, again.

Comment: Don't know if it's possible but you can try it out I suppose. If you feel that the answer was good enough, please also make sure to go ahead and make it the accepted one.